# Opening a half page when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to open a kind of a new page when clicking on a button. For example, I have some items that vertically and horizontally center in the page. I want it so that when the button is clicked, it will move all my items to the left half of the page and open a new page on the right half page. 
This is my example code:
**HTML:**

```
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<button>
Click me
</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And this is my goal when someone clicks on the button:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you truly want the contents to come from a different URL to show on the right, you can do this with an `iframe` or an AJAX call. Both solutions would require the container to change its width upon successful loading of content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this if it help you. then give me a feedback if it needs to improve or not?

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('.new-content').toggleClass('half').delay(600).fadeIn(100);
  $('.content-container').toggleClass('half');
});
```

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.new-content {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f60;
}
.new-content.half,
.content-container.half {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">
  <div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<button id="button">
Click me
</button>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="new-content">
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have a small problem. As you can see here your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/92ej91p2/ , I add a text on the 50% new screen that opens, but when I clicked the button again, the text is not dissapper and hide, he goes to the right and stay there. How I can hide all the text in the "new-content" when the new-content class is not opens? (In the beginning it doesn't show anything, but after one click on the button and then another click to close the new half screen, it still shows the text). Thanks!

Comment: Hi, just add `overflow: hidden;` to `.new-content` class.

Comment: Thanks again sir! Sorry for it.

Comment: Hi, one more problem I have now: When the second half screen has no more space to write on it, is no possibility to go down (I meant with the mouse) after I finished to write on the 100 VH height. Therefore, I deleted it and it works, however, when I closed the half screen again - I can see that the whole page have the option to scroll down (Although my main page not have nothing to scroll down), so how I can fix it? Thanks again! @mohamad faramarzi

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example that uses **[`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)** elements that loads up your content and external content at the same time:

```css
html, body, #wrapper {height:100%;}

#left {float:left; width: 50%; background-color:yellow; height:100%; padding:0;margin:0;}
#right {float:left; width:49%; background-color:grey; height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    This is the original content
  </div>
  <iframe id="right" src="https://example.com">
    This is where the new content goes
  </iframe>
</div>
```

And here'a an example that uses **[AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)** to accomplish what you are asking for. But, you will need to substitute your URL for the "page2" data into this example. This would be useful when you want more control over the fetching and consumption of the external data.

```js
// Get a reference to the "right" container
var right = document.getElementById("right");

// Instantiate a new AJAX component
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Set up the component to respond to changes in its state
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(){
  // If the request is complete
  if(xhr.readyState === 4){
    
    // If the result was successful
    if(xhr.status === 200){
      // successful call
      // Set the right content area to the returned value of the AJAX call
      right.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      
      // Change the widths of the div elements so that the right area
      // is now shown and the left area shrinks down
      left.style.width = "50%";
      right.style.width = "50%";
    }
  }
});

// Configure the AJAX request. You need to supply a URL
// on your server to get the new page data from:
xhr.open("GET", "SomeURL");

// Make the request
xhr.send();
```

```css
html, body, #wrapper {height:100%;}

/* 
  In reality, change the left width to 100% and the right width to 0 here 
  The JavaScript will modify the values to 50/50. I've only set the values
  to 50/50 to show how the results will look
*/
#left {float:left; width: 50%; background-color:yellow; height:100%; padding:0;margin:0;}
#right {float:left; width:50%; background-color:grey; height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    This is the original content
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    This is where the new content goes
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking good, but I prefer a eaiser solution like someone did, but thanks I studied alot from this too

Comment: @WebO  The answer you've selected is not an answer to the question you asked since it does absolutely nothing to load a second page. It turns out that you wanted was to know how to hide half of the CURRENT page and then show it later. That's not what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable using a js framework, this can be done easily using angularJs.

Simply create and angular module, a controller for that module, and some boolean to render the left and right side divs. I called this boolean `clicked`, code below:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="center-box" ng-if="!clicked">
  <p>{{Item1}}</p>
  <p>{{Item2}}</p>
  <p>{{Item3}}</p>
  <button ng-click="setClicked()"> Click me </button>
</div>
<div class="r-half" ng-if="clicked">
   <div style="text-align:center;">
    My new Page here
  </div>
</div>
<div class="l-half" ng-if="clicked">
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <p>{{Item1}}</p>
    <p>{{Item2}}</p>
    <p>{{Item3}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.Item1 = "myItem";
    $scope.Item2 = "anotherItem";
    $scope.Item3 = "aThirdItem";

    $scope.clicked = false;

    $scope.setClicked = function(){
        $scope.clicked = !$scope.clicked;
    }

});
```

CSS:

```
.center-box {
  text-align:center;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.r-half {
  width:50%;
  float:right;
  height:100%
}

.l-half {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  height:100%
}
```

A link to my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Jack_Hamby/c06gd2z4/

Comment: Thank you, studied from this too

Answer (score 1):

Lose the `body` tag in the css.
Instead, create 2 `<div>` elements in your body.
Use the `float` css attribute to set them side by side:

```css
.div1 {
    height:400px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

.div2 {
    height:400px;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    display:none;
}
```

After that, when clicking your button, display div2.

In your HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class='div1'>content 1</div>
   <div class='div2'>content 2</div>
</body>
```